# how to create margin between bootstrap columns without destroying design?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have my simple markup

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 loginField">
data

    </div>
    <div class=" col-lg-6 loginField">
        <div class="">
            test
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

.loginField{
background-color:white;
}
```

so my problem is that i am getting 1 white line on desktop screen, but i want to make a 10 px space between those 2 columns without destroying responsive design. Right now if i switch to smaller screen it works, but on desctop there are no space, and if i add margin, this margin presist on smaller screens which is ugly.
P.S. when i say it works on smaller screens, i mean that those 2 columns move under each other and width of the white lines are as they shopuld be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to mimic the same breakpoints in the responsive design as is in bootstrap.css:

http://jsfiddle.net/G6nWh/4/

**CSS:**

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .margin-left-10 { margin-left: 10px; }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="col-lg-6 loginField">
    <div class="margin-left-10">
        test
    </div>
</div>
```

If you have changed the breakpoints, you'll need to update that `min-width`, but this is the default `min-width` for Bootstrap's large columns.

When the screen gets smaller, the rule stops being applied, so it won't affect your smaller screens.

Comment: if you remove gray color problem is still there

Comment: @Timsen Sorry, which problem? As I understood it, you wanted `margin-left` only on large screens, not in small screens. Was there something else?

Comment: I think its just me who are failing hard, but can you make a more precise example where there are 10 px margin between those 2 'col-lg-6'. because right now content inside second column is just pushed 10px to the side, but i want to push whole column to the right, because i want to use that white background color.

Comment: Oh I see! Sorry, having an exact 10px margin-left between the two columns is not neatly possible. The best option, that I outlined above, is to have an inner element doing the margin (so, put the `background-colour` on a wrapping 'inner element', one of which has a 10px left margin) and it will do what you want. The only option, if you want to keep `background-color` on the `col-lg-6`s themselves, is to have a larger margin (defined by a percentage, by using `.col-lg-offset-1` and removing 1 unit of size from one of the columns,  so: ... 1/2

Comment: `<div class="col-lg-6">One</div><div class="col-lg-5 col-lg-offset-1">Two</div>`. 2/2

Comment: Just figured it out :) you guided me in the right direction by using @media. I just created 2 new classes colLeft and colRight, and just differ padding when desctop screen is in use :  <div class="col-lg-6 innerLeft">